# What is the difference between secretary and personal assistant?

Tags: word-choice

What is the difference between *secretary* and *personal assistant*?

> Also - keep in mind that for high-level execs or company owners, the jobs is not **secretary** or admin assistant, it is **personal assistant**.

Comment: Are you asking a language-related question? It seems like you are asking about the work responsibilities of people with those titles. That might be better to ask on [Workplace SE](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/). Informal titles are just that.

Comment: Unless you're a Secretary of State, personal assistant sounds more impressive!

Comment: The specifics of what a particular job title entails will vary from job to job, organization to organization, industry to industry, and location to location, but it would serve you well to begin by looking up [basic descriptions](https://nationalcareersservice.direct.gov.uk/job-profiles/personal-assistant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though the responsibilities are usually the same in terms of helping their executive boss.

> personal assistant

or **PA**, is a more formal sounding title than secretary, in the same way that

> sanitation engineer

is a more formal title for a *garbage collector*.

Comment: It should be noted that “sanitation engineer” is a bit of a misnomer for trash collector. [Sanitary engineering is a bona fide career field](http://www.allstarjobs.com/careers/Environmental_Science/Sanitation_Engineer) that goes beyond picking up garbage and putting it in a truck. Still, the [misperception exists](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/sanitation%20engineer).